# How to parse several hardcoded keys in JSON API struct with Swift Decodable protocol?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift4

Question: I am trying to decode my JSON, which some of the JSON will have a random string and some will have a hardcoded string. When the hardcoded string is one of the below, I would like to display different UICollectionView Cells. I am having trouble trying to parse my JSON if it is a hardcoded string and being able to display a different UICollectionViewCell with it. Any help on this would be great. This may be a beginner question but I have tried to solve this for this past week and I am having trouble trying to do it. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
**  Hardcoded Strings that could be one or the other:**
key: --> This string could be "breaking" or "normal" or "new"
item: --> This string could be "placement" or "slot" or "shared"
verb: --> This string could be "shared" or "posted"

** NOT hardcoded strings, which the string comes in randomly**
heading: --> This string is a random string
type: --> This string is a random string
```

Here is some of my JSON, so you can get an example of what I am trying to do:

```
    {
    slots: [
        {
        key: "breaking",
        item: "placement",
        heading: "Random String Text",
        type: "Random String Text",
        via: "Random",
        verb: "shared"
        sort_order: 0
        },
        {
        key: "breaking",
        item: "placement",
        heading: "Random String Text",
        type: "Random String Text",
        via: "Random",
        verb: "posted"
        sort_order: 1
        },
        {
        key: "event",
        item: "combine",
        heading: "Random String Text",
        type: "Random String Text",
        via: "Random",
        verb: "posted"
        sort_order: 2
        },
}
```

This is what I have so far for my model:

```
struct MyModel: Decodable {
    var key: String?
    var item: String?
    var heading: String?
    var type: String?
    var via: String?
    var verb: String?
}
```

Here is an example cell that Dmitry Serov helped me with.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let model = ... // retrieve your model object here
   if model.verb == .shared {
     // Pass the pertinent identifier
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:...)
     return cell
   else {
     ....
   }
 }
```

Here is more code that Dmitry Serov helped me with.

```
struct MyModel { // Type names should use pascal case in Swift
  var verb: State?
  ....
  enum State {
    case shared
    case posted
  }
}

// Decode your enums from strings
extension MyModel.State: Decodable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case shared
    case posted
  }
}
```

The issue when I try the above it is asking me to put in the format below which I am not sure how to do and I am trying to parse out several more keys.

```
extension MyModel.State: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way I would decode your json using codable:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var slots = [Slots]()
}

struct Slots: Codable {
    var key: String?
    var item: String?
    var heading: String?
    var type: String?
    var via: String?
    var verb: String?
    var order: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case order = "sort_order"
    }
    /** Custom Encoder to send null values**/
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try? container.encode(order, forKey: .order)
    }

}
```

To compare with hardcoded strings create an enum:

```
enum key: String {
    case breking
    case normal
    case new
}
```

use it like this:

```
if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: response.data!){
for slot in response.slots{
    if slot.key == key.breaking.rawValue{
    //do something
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but in this code doesn't show any of the hardcoded strings or being able to show different UIcollectioview Cells based on the hardcoded strings that I stated above...

Comment: Thanks! I will try. How can I create an extension for this? And where do I put the "enum key:" and the if let response = try? ...". Where do I put that in the code?

Comment: I suppose you are getting your JSON from a server, right?... on your server response put the JSONDecoder and from ther you can pass it to you view controller, there on you UIVIewCollection delegates funcs put the if comparison

Comment: Do I need an extension for this or the code that you have put is fine? Do I just add the "if let response = try? ..." into the UICollectionView Controller?

Comment: Yes, I am getting it from a server. Can we go on the stackoverflow chat?

Comment: sure, I 'll be able to explain better

Comment: How can we make the stackoverflow chat come up?

Comment: It says I dont have enough to chat. Do you have Skype where I can add you?

Comment: you dont have enough reputation to use chat, here is a link explainig it https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat

Comment: Where would I put the Enum? Can you show me the complete code for what you gave me and how I can use this on my UICollectionView Controller?

Comment: @ Sergio Trejo can we go on a skype chat, I am confused on this. Thanks!